# How to read data from SQLiteOpenHelper to textview?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I want to set Textview from SQL database, but the app crashes when I launch this activity. Where is the problem?

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
Cursor readAllData(){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    if(db != null){
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
myDB = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity2.this);
Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
btn.setText(cursor.getString(5));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the stacktrace to better understand the crash. However, you probably get the crash because you're querying your database from the UI thread, when you should query it in a separate and secure one.

Here's an example, using the code that you provided:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompactActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButtonId);

        new Thread(() -> {
            SQLiteDatabase myDB = new DatabaseHelper(YourActivity.this);
            Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
            String textToShow = cursor.getString(5);
            
            //Now that you've done all the work needed, you can go to the UiThread
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                btn.setText(textToShow);
            }
        }



}
```